# WooCommerce Issue After Upgraded to The latest version

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment

Once I have upgraded WooCommerce plugin to the latest version I started getting this error in the error_log file:
`10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_last_name was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_address_1 was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_address_2 was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_postcode was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_country was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_phone was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_first_name was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_last_name was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_phone was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_address_1 was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_state was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_city was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_postcode was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_postcode was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_country was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_email was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] order_total was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_first_name was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] billing_last_name was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] shipping_address_1 was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] shipping_address_2 was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] shipping_city was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] shipping_state was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] shipping_country was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[10-May-2017 12:19:25 UTC] shipping_postcode was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->process_payment, WC_Gateway_payroll_creditcard_wc->get_payroll_args, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.`

How Can if fix the plugin, this is the code:

Comment: The code is here : https://pastebin.com/ZC4evChr

Comment: read the texts... it has the clue...

Comment: Dear @Reigel, I have read it, I couldn't figure out how to fix it, thats why I posted it here.

Comment: The payment gateway `Payroll` plugin is not up to date, so not compatible with WooCommerce version 3.0+ … That's all. So you have to ask the authors from this plugin, in their support threads. Here in StackOverFlow we don't fix plugins.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I have developed the plugin but i am not able to fix this issue.

Comment: You have to look to the new WC_order, WC_Cart and WC_Product  methods as you can access properties directly now:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html …
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html …
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html …

So you have to use new setters and getters methods instead of properties on woocommerce objects